# My J2ME application take a long time to start running?

Tags: java-me

I make a j2me application that almost all of it, are text files.

size: 3mb

The problem is, when I run it on my mobile, it take about 10 sec to run. I do nothing on startup. I have another app with size: 7mb, but it runs without any delay!

Jar files link:

mine: http://s1.picofile.com/file/7252355799/mine.jar.html

correct one: http://s1.picofile.com/file/7252346448/correctone.jar.html

install both of them and run. mine take some seconds to show up, but the other shows immediately.

Comment: add to the post the code of the main midlet

Comment: I just show a canvas in main midlet. when i remove the text files, my app show on mobile screen normally (after running)! it's interesting that the text files did not use in app!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take into account that **[JAR is a compressed file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29)**.

To use jar file contents, device has to first de-compress it. How long does decompression take very much depends on jar **contents** and because of that, jar file size may be not directly related to startup delay.

You better use some zip tool (most if not all such tools can handle jar format) to learn about contents of the jar files you work with - this might give you better indication on what to expect at startup.

- For example, I can easily imagine your "7 mb" jar file containing just a handful of jpeg images of total size, well, about same 7 mb - and decompressing very quickly.
  As for "3 mb of text files" - if these decompress to something like few hundreds files of total size 50 mb then I would not wonder if it takes long to unpack at device startup.

Comment: you're welcome. By the way you can also take a look at an "instruction" explaining how we at StackOverflow deal with _helpful_ answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/165773